# Commerce module "Add to cart" is displayed as "Product not available"

Tags: commerce

I am n newbie into Drupal.
I've added new Product and in the store for this product it shows PRODUCT NOT AVAILABLE and the button is disabled.(there is no Add to cart).
Product is active and is displayed in catalogue.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! :) You have to provide more details about your setup: which modules are you using, did you use Commerce Kickstart as a starting point for your website, etc.

Comment: If you have [Commerce Stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock) module then try to disable that module & check.

Comment: @NishantP, I have not enabled Commerce stock module.

Comment: @Topsitemakers, I am using commerce contrib module and not commerce kickstart distribution.